# Is it possible to use two separate USB tuners with Windows Media Center?

Tags: usb, windows-media-center, tv, tuner-card, dvb-t

I'm planning to replace my traditional 'big box' Core 2 Duo media center (with twin tuners) with an <s>Asrock Ion 3D</s> Zacate-based µATX system, but this means forgoing my existing PCI-E dual tuner card for a USB solution.  Since Freeview HD (using DVB-T2) is now available I'd like to equip my media center to take advantage.

The trouble is there are currently no dual DVB-T2 USB tuners on the market (that I can find anyway).

Would I be able to plug two separate USB tuners and have them correctly picked up and working within all apps, including Windows Media Center?  Are there any caveats I might need to bear in mind when using two tuners in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yes you can](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-should-I-know-before-adding-TV-tuners-to-use-with-Windows-Media-Center).

There really aren't any caveats; most dual TV tuners are recognized as separate devices to the computer anyway.

EDIT: And apparently, you can [add even more](http://cybernetnews.com/cybernotes-multiple-tuners-in-vista-media-center-mce/).

Comment: What "other apps" are you talking about? Just curious, why WMC?

Comment: Thanks, but unless I'm missing something the MS link only confirms that more than one tuner device can be added to WMC, and while use of more than one USB tuner may be implied there is no positive confirmation that two discrete USB tuners will not be a problem.

Comment: Here are some more links with info: [This forum topic here](http://mc.anywherecool.com/Forum/default.aspx?g=posts&m=33), and [this Hauppauge forum topic here](http://www.hauppauge.co.uk/board/showthread.php?19422-2-x-WinTV-HVR-900-but-only-1-works). [This forum post](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1518042) is probably the closest to what you want to hear.

Comment: Cheers, have some bounty!